# Get child by class name from a specific parent id

Tags: jquery

I have the following html in the dom:

```
<div class="four columns mobile_right flex" id="quantity_1">
  <button class="qtyminus" role="button"></button>
  <span class="quantity_label">Qty:</span>
  <input type="number" min="0" size="2" class="quantity" name="updates[]" id="updates_33467117961304" value="1">
  <button class="qtyplus" role="button"></button>
</div>
```

I need to get and adjust the value of .quantity but related to the parent since there is a several quantity elements in the dom (when multiple products are loaded).

My attempt is:

```
$('.qtyplus').on('click', function(e) {
    var qtyId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    var qtyParent = '.' + qtyId;
    var qtyValClass = $(qtyParent).find('.quantity');
    console.log(qtyValClass.val());
})
```

This returns undefined.  I'm dong something wrong when trying to get the element but can't figure out what it is.  Any idea?

Comment: What element is `this`?

Comment: There is no element with `class="quantity_1"`, so what do you expect `$(qtyParent)` to select? Why not just `$(this).parent().find(".quantity")`?

Comment: sorry just updated, it's .qtyplus

Comment: Or `$(this).siblings(".quantity")`

Comment: Since it appears you are firing an event on the buttons, and you are using jquery, why not use `$(this).siblings('input.quantity')`?

Comment: a man I'm such a dummy ya it's an id not a class

Comment: But there's no need to select an element by ID or class when you have a reference to the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is unnecessary to complicate the work using ID. This way you can make more specific uses.

```js
$('.qtyplus').on('click', function(e) {

var quantity = $(this).closest('.quantity_control').find('.quantity').val();
   
console.log(quantity);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="four columns mobile_right flex quantity_control" id="quantity_1">
  <button class="qtyminus" role="button">-</button>
  <span class="quantity_label">Qty:</span>
  <input type="number" min="0" size="2" class="quantity" name="updates[]" id="updates_33467117961304" value="1">
  <button class="qtyplus" role="button">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Barmar and @Ryan Wilson I achieved by using 'siblings'

```
$('.qtyplus').on('click', function(e) {
    var qty = parseInt( $(this).siblings(".quantity").val() );
})
```